# How do I get mu on change event to populate the input from one field into the input of another field

Tags: javascript, if-statement, wildcard, onchange

I'm trying to say in my code below that when field1.value is input, populate field2 with that value/text.  this is being done through an on change event,  but its not running the way I think it should.

this works:

`if (field1.value=='Hello') {field2.value='World'} else {field2.value='foo';}`

> but I'm trying to get the below to work and its not:

if (field1.value=='%') {field2.value='field1.value'}
else {field2.value='';}

Answer (score 0):

`'field1.value'` is literally the *string* `'field1.value'` 
I assume you want the *value* of `field1.value` 
Try this:

```
if (field1.value=='%') {
    field2.value=field1.value
} 
else {
    field2.value='';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes around `= 'field1.value'`.

Here's a working example.

```js
document.getElementById("field1").addEventListener("keyup", function(){
  if(this.value == "%")
    document.getElementById("field2").value = this.value;
  else
    document.getElementById("field2").value = "";
});
```

```html
Put a % in this box: <input id="field1" type="text"/>
<br>
Second box: <input id="field2" type="text" readonly/>
```